# Does doxygen support python argument type hints?

Tags: python, doxygen, type-hinting

Given the function predicate below, doxygen seems to truncate after `test_point_count`
is there any configuration option in the Doxyfile which can rectify this?  Unfortunately, I am stuck with doxygen version 1.8.5 and I don't see much that references python compatibility.

```py
def expect_equal(logger, test_point_count: int, expected: any, actual: any, tolerance: float = 0, desc: str = ""):
    """
    Logging helper comparing 2 values and logging results
    @param logger: Logger used for outputting results
    @param test_point_count: iterator value for tp count
    @param expected: expected value for test 
    @param actual: actual result of test
    @param tolerance: float describing the +/- tolerance for check
    @param desc: str description of test and results
    """
```

Comment: not used doxygen, but could perhaps be related to the type hints: did you mean `Any` instead of `any`, which starts after `test_point_count`?

Comment: I'm not really knowledgeable in python.  if that is incorrect I can change it, but it seems to work.  However the doxygen reported abstract truncate prior to ": int"

Comment: Doxygen 1.8.5 is very very old (August 23, 2013), the current doxygen version is 1.9.8 Why are you stuck with 1.8.5? Which version of python do you use? @joel hinted in the directions of the so called type hints and in the doxygen 1.8.5 version  there was no support for these type hints, so doxygen stopped processing the definition at that point). I would very strongly advise you to update doxygen. Besides this problem there are many more features e.g. the setting `PYTHON_DOCSTRING` (see https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_python_docstring)

Comment: @albert I work it a closed environment where software upgrades have to go through a lengthy review process.  It can happen.  It just won't happen within a few weeks.  So I would like to know the issue for sure rather than blindly putting in for an upgrade.  As for your second comment I will look into this but it appears to be failing at the type hint of "int", not "any".

Comment: I understand that a closed environment can have some restrictions in respect to software updates. As far as I can see the mentioned problem is solved in the current, 1.9.8, version. A solution is to remove the type hints and the default value but I think that this will result in more problems / has a bigger resistance in your, closed,  environment. Maybe you can do some tests in a local environment.